# How to resolve the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.SDKGlobalConfiguration.isInRegionOptimizedModeEnabled()Z?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to S3 and getting error like

> Target exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.amazonaws.SDKGlobalConfiguration.isInRegionOptimizedModeEnabled()Z

Code is

```
 String accessKey="accesskey";
 String secretKey="mysecretkey"

  AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
  AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

In the line of   `AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);` I am getting the target exception.

Totally I imported these many java packages showing below. still getting the same error.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import com.amazonaws.auth.*;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.util.StringUtils;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.SDKGlobalConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Bucket;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GeneratePresignedUrlRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectListing;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.*;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory;
import com.amazonaws.annotation.NotThreadSafe;
import com.amazonaws.annotation.SdkTestInternalApi;
import com.amazonaws.client.AwsSyncClientParams;
import com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFunction;
import com.amazonaws.regions.AwsRegionProvider;

import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.Protocol;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
```

Comment: did you find the answer ?

Comment: No. I am not working on this technology now